# How to disable automatic launching of the Touch Keyboard

Tags: windows-8, accessibility, touch-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permanently remove/disable Touch Keyboard in Windows 8 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/488322/permanently-remove-disable-touch-keyboard-in-windows-8-taskbar)

In Taskbar Properties under Toolbars, if I uncheck **Touch Keyboard** and restart, after signing in again it will be checked and docked in the Taskbar.

[image: Touch Keyboard Taskbar]

Any idea why my changes aren't kept?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons why your setting is not permanent:

1.application that tries to set setting don’t have rights (in this case explorer.exe)

2.some other software change the value back after restart (could be malware)

So try exit `explorer.exe` and then run it as administrator (to check first possibility) or try to disable all startup apps and also all non-Microsoft services (both could be found in "msconfig"), restart and try to disable Touch Keyboard one more time.
I none of this works, you can use system restore to get back to time, when the keyboard wasn't checked (if you got restore point old enough).

Answer (score 0):

This [thread on MSA](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-tms/disable-touch-keyboard-on-a-tablet-when-a-keyboard/3493d931-2f7b-4934-9cfa-ebfcb681a93a) suggests you have to disable the Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel service in `services.msc`.