# How disable Windows 10 keyboard helper?

Tags: windows-10

After updating my system with Windows 10, every time I click on a text box this helper appears.

I think is something for a tablet. But I don't want it! I'm in a laptop.
How I can disable it permanently?

I have a Wacom tablet.

This is an image of the helper
[image: keyboard helper background was blurred for privacy]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently remove/disable Touch Keyboard in Windows 8 taskbar?](http://superuser.com/questions/488322/permanently-remove-disable-touch-keyboard-in-windows-8-taskbar)

Comment: I have a few wacom tablets and I have seen this issue. This solution worked for me: http://superuser.com/questions/488322/permanently-remove-disable-touch-keyboard-in-windows-8-taskbar/514534#514534