# How to disable Windows 10 handwritting dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-10, handwriting-recognition

I have upgraded my PC to Windows 10, I have a [Wacom Bamboo tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacom_%28company%29#Bamboo) connected to it, and now every time I click into an editable control or app using my tablet, a very annoying window pops up, related to hand-writing recognition.

[image]

**How can I disable this thing in Windows 10?** I have tried several tutorials that I found online, designed for previous versions of Windows, and in all cases I could not find in Windows 10 some of the options they refer to.

Comment: You have installed Windows 10 compatible drivers for your device?

Comment: Yes, I did, from the wacom website, otherwise the tablet is not even detected by the OS

Comment: Finally, this worked: http://superuser.com/a/514534/141817

Answer (score 7):

To turn it off:

1. Open the start menu and search for "Services" and click on the result
2. Find "Touch keyboard and handwriting panel service"
3. Right click and select "Stop"
4. Right click on "Properties"
5. Under "Startup type:" select "disabled"
6. Click OK to save.

Comment: This is just a copy of one of the answers in the OP comment link.

Comment: I'd not mark this as a duplicate, given the question is for a different context: drawing tablet != touch keyboard. The solution is the same, but for different problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get rid of that stupid dialog. Nobody on the internet has done it. It's forced by Microsoft because they don't want people using pens.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up what you're saying?

Comment: Your answer is wrong. See [Permanently remove/disable Touch Keyboard in Windows 8 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/a/514534) which the OP has said answers his question.